# Error message: ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a Python script to find an X coordinate of the circle center. If the `r1` is small the `xA1` and `xA2` are complex numbers, so I sometimes get the error message: `ValueError: math domain error`.

How can I use a while-loop to keep trying? Must I copy the entire code below the while statement? Is it possible to make a link to the first equation `xs2=r3*math.sin(beta2r)`?

```
import math

r1=0;
r2=110.5;              
r3=212.5;              
beta2d=35;             
beta1dpoz=45;          

beta2r=beta2d*math.pi/180

xs2=r3*math.sin(beta2r)     
ys2=r1-r3*math.cos(beta2r) 

kruh1=math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2)                         
kruh2=math.pow(r1,2)+math.pow(r3,2)-2*r1*r3*math.cos(beta2r)

xA1=1.0/2*((xs2*(1+((math.pow(r1,2)-math.pow(r2,2))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2)))))+(ys2*(math.sqrt(((2*(math.pow(r1,2)+math.pow(r2,2)))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2)))-(math.pow(((math.pow(r1,2)-math.pow(r2,2))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2))),2))-1))))
xA2=1.0/2*((xs2*(1+((math.pow(r1,2)-math.pow(r2,2))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2)))))-(ys2*(math.sqrt(((2*(math.pow(r1,2)+math.pow(r2,2)))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2)))-(math.pow(((math.pow(r1,2)-math.pow(r2,2))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2))),2))-1))))

xAmat=[xA1,xA2]

xA=max(xAmat) 

while ('ValueError: math domain error'):   
    r1=r1+0.1
.
.
.
xA=
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? As it is, your while loop will loop forever, as condition is a non-empty string, which always evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Oh my goodness, would you look at how long those two lines are.

Comment: Do you want it to stop as soon as the calculations produce a value, NOT an error?

Comment: Yes exactly, I looking for a first number which is not complex (not an error)

Comment: I looking for a first number which is not complex (not an error). The two lines are very long I know. They are represents intersection of two circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will increment `r1` until `xA1` and `xA2` are valid.

```
import math

r1=0;
r2=110.5;              #vstupny polomer
r3=212.5;              #vystupny polomer
beta2d=35;             #vystupny uhel
beta1dpoz=45;          #vstupny uhel

xA1, xA2 = None, None
#Keep looping till xA1 and xA2 are valid
while xA1 == None and xA2 == None:

    beta2r=beta2d*math.pi/180

    xs2=r3*math.sin(beta2r)     
    ys2=r1-r3*math.cos(beta2r) 

    kruh1=math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2)                         
    kruh2=math.pow(r1,2)+math.pow(r3,2)-2*r1*r3*math.cos(beta2r)
    
    try:
        xA1=1.0/2*((xs2*(1+((math.pow(r1,2)-math.pow(r2,2))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2)))))+(ys2*(math.sqrt(((2*(math.pow(r1,2)+math.pow(r2,2)))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2)))-(math.pow(((math.pow(r1,2)-math.pow(r2,2))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2))),2))-1))))
        xA2=1.0/2*((xs2*(1+((math.pow(r1,2)-math.pow(r2,2))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2)))))-(ys2*(math.sqrt(((2*(math.pow(r1,2)+math.pow(r2,2)))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2)))-(math.pow(((math.pow(r1,2)-math.pow(r2,2))/(math.pow(xs2,2)+math.pow(ys2,2))),2))-1))))
    except ValueError:
        r1 += 0.1

xAmat=[xA1,xA2]
xA=max(xAmat)
```

If it is possible for any of the other calculations (`beta2r,s2, xs2, kruh1, kruh1`) to produce a `ValueError` then move the `try` statement up to encompass those as well.

You may want to read [the documentation for the `try` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement).

Comment: Thank You very much. It works :) and now I understood a principle as well. I programmed this script originally for Octave. There is a different principle. Thank you for your time :)